# Firefox window in GNOME extends beyond visible frame

Tags: gnome, firefox

I am using GNOME 43 and have been having this issue where the Firefox window occupies more space than it is supposed to. It is like it has an invisible halo around the window that is very annoying when trying to click on other windows.

I have recorded a video of this behavior in this link: https://workdrive.zohoexternal.com/file/b6s8q3223e25a12d34270a35e4f4d2940d1e8

I tried to find this issue reported before, but could find nothing.

Does anyone know how to disable this invisible halo around the window? It only happens with Firefox so far as I can tell. However, Telegram Desktop seem to have a similar situation, only here I can see a sort of shadow around the window and the actual window size is reduced:

[image: Telegram Desktop window]

Hope anyone can help with this issue.

Cheers.